# Junit error in newlly created Androidstudio 2.0 projects

Tags: android-studio, gradle

> I'm sorry if my question is awkward because I'm a novice programmer.

I use Android studio 2, gradle 2.10 and Windows 10. After I create a new project, gradle starts to sync the project.

After the sync completes, I enable "work offline" mode for gradle in the settings. The sync happens again for every new project I create. When I enable "work offline" I receive this error during the build. How should I solve the problem?

**Error:(23, 17) Failed to resolve: junit:junit:4.12**

[The screenshot of my build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JavOD.png)

Comment: This is possibly a bug (in project template files) in androidstudio 2 since I had the problem on two separate machines (my students had it too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the "`testCompile junit:junit:4.12`" from build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'  //remove this line and sync again... worked for me
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
      }
```

Comment: @Susano Joon no Just open your build.gradle file and change in dependencies as a suggest.

Comment: I do not have a problem with the removal of the code in the future?

Comment: After that, Should I enable "work offline" for gradle??

Comment: @SusanoJoon no Need for that.

Comment: thank you
  The first problem was resolved
But I did not notice and I still uncertainty

Comment: @SusanoJoon now your project in run or not ?

Comment: run ,
But I have to repeat for every new project,
Also, if the option is not enabled, the process will take time!

Comment: @SusanoJoon ok If my answer is helpful then mark it as accepted.so other person get the solution and also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the following to your build.gradle file and it should work fine.

add this code to build.gradle.. it will work.

```
repositories {
            maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
            jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/" }
        }

       android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.application"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "3.0"
        }
        buildTypes {

            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    }
```